# What does the http accept header exactly means?

Tags: http-headers

I read [this](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) but still confused. So if I received a Accept header like this: `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8`

And I want to parse it to be this form:

```
[
    {
        mine:mine1,
        q: q1
    },
            {
        mine:mine2,
        q: q2
    }
    ....
]
```

What would the result be like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `q` applies to the single MIME type before it. From the HTTP 1.1 RFC that you linked to:

> Each media-range MAY be followed by one or more accept-params, beginning with the "q" parameter

So the q is associated with the media range (MIME type) that it follows.

Later on, the following example is given:

> A more elaborate example is
>
> ```
>   Accept: text/plain; q=0.5, text/html,
>           text/x-dvi; q=0.8, text/x-c
> ```
>
> Verbally, this would be interpreted as "text/html and text/x-c are the
>   preferred media types, but if they do not exist, then send the text/x-dvi
>   entity, and if that does not exist, send the text/plain entity."

You can see that `text/html` and `text/x-c`, which have no `q`, are the highest quality, followed by `text/x-dvi` at 0.8, and then `text/plain` with 0.5.

Thus your example might be parsed as

```
[
    {
        mine: "text/html"
    },
    {
        mine: "application/xhtml+xml"
    },
    {
        mine: "application/xml",
        q: "0.9"
    },
    {
        mine: "image/webp"
    },
    {
        mine: "image/apng"
    },
    {
        mine: "*/*",
        q: "0.8"
    }
]
```

Alternatively, you might default `q` to `"1.0"` when parsing the string.